# Can pyramid configuration be accessed after the fact

Tags: configuration, pyramid

The common initialization for a pyramid app, roughly speaking, is:

1. create Configurator object
2. call various methods on Configurator object such as .include(), or .set_authorization_policy()
3. create the wsgi app by calling .make_wsgi_app() on the Configurator object.

Once step 3 is done, and your application is running, is there any way to access the values assigned in step 2? For example, can I query my pyramid app to get a reference to the authorization policy object that I set in step 2?

Michael

Answer (score 1):

Pyramid has an "introspector" API [1] which allows you to query most information about your application configuration. It is not super friendly to use because it is defined very generally.

```
introspector = request.registry.introspector
authn_intr = introspector.get('authentication policy', None)
policy = authn_intr['policy']
```

[1] http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/pyramid/en/latest/narr/introspector.html